# jQuery.hide is not accepting parameters

Tags: jquery, yui

I've used jQuery for some months with good results, but today I'm facing something weird. This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
```

Following code works fine in another page of the same project (I myself did it some months ago):

```
$(hideButtonJQId).click(function (){
    $(this).hide("slow", function (){
    ... do something
    });
});
```

For some reason, in the new page, hide is only working without parameters:

```
$(hideButtonJQId).click(function (){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

If I try to set any parameter, even just a delay parameter, it throws errors:

```
$(hideButtonJQId).click(function (){
    $(this).hide(1000);
    $(this).hide('slow');
    $(this).hide('slow', function{ alert('not working'); });
    etc.
});
```

The error in FireBug is "*c.replace is not a function*".

We're using YUI framework in both pages, the one where it works fine, and the one where it doesn't. I've thought it could be a crash between frameworks but the error message I'm getting from FireBug comes from **jquery-1.6.1.min.js** file. I would really appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried using `jQuery` instead of `$` and turned on compatibility mode?

Comment: Thank you Blender, I just tried your suggestion by adding following piece of code just below jQuery script insertion:

<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

And I replaced every $ reference with 'jQuery', but the error message remains. I'll keep researching, thanks agian.

Comment: Can you post your `<head>` tag contents and how you're running the script?

Comment: @Blender thank you very much for your assistance.

I finally found the library that was crashing jQuery (a json library). I guess I have to improve my code about compatibility mode I tried before at your suggestion since our jQuery plugin worked fine when I commented out such jSon library that was causing the issue. Best regards.

Comment: Please post your findings as an answer below and then accept your own answer.

Comment: Sure @Sparky672, the web page asked me to wait some time to answer my own question.

Comment: Actually, I have to wait 8 hours. I'll do it tomorrow, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is about libraries collisions. If you face similar problems, you may refer following references to use compatibility mode and jQuery plugins authoring.

[Plugins Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

[Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)

In the beginning, I thought it wasn't a collision issue due to error was thrown from jQuery's JS file, **but** I guess that the very first invocation was done to the other library's JS file that in the end finished being executed in jQuery. In the case of Internet Explorer, it showed the error in a different JS file, that was the way I realize the fix.

I hope it helps, kind regards to everyone.

Answer (score -1):

This happens if your selector returns an undefined value. Make sure your selector returns a valid value.
Check what is this pointing to when it hits $(this).hide();

Comment: Hi Rohan. I have inspected with FireBug both, the object **$(this)**, and the function **$(this).hide**, they seem correct. Thanks :)

Comment: @Rohan, Any garbage selector should never cause a JS error. It will simply return an empty jQuery object and calling any of its methods will do nothing.